# C# XNA published game can't run and getting the installation location

Tags: c#, xna, admin, publish, installation-path

I have been trying to create my first error log for my game and I've run into some problems. First of all, I try to create a text file using:

```
errorLog = new StreamWriter("c:\\ErrorLog.txt", true);
```

However I can only run the game through the Setup.exe after installing the game because it's the only executable that I can assign admin rights to, the game shortcut doesn't have that option. Whenever I try to run the game from somewhere else I just get "program has stopped responding".

My second problem is creating the text file where I want it, I want to create it where the game was installed from which is "c:\Program Files (x86)\MyGame". I've tried using several different methods:

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
Path.GetDirectoryName(baseDir);
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

But they all return a giant path in my local AppData. I don't know if this makes a difference but this is with a click once application.

Thankyou in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because ClickOnce applications are installed under the profile of the user who installed them.

You can use `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` which is probably what you're looking for, or even better:

```
private string GetDataDirectory()
{
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory;
    else
        return Application.StartupPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`?